# Inner AsyncTask not updating member variables in outer class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that in one of it's Activities uses AsyncTask to call a method from another class that hooks up to a database to varify a user's login credentials. The Activity EntryActivity Has three member variable that need to be updated with the result of the AsyncTask, carerID, firstName and surName . When I first run the App all three variables are null but if i press the login button a second time the variables are set correctly and the app behaves as it should.

Is there a reason why the three member variables are not set correctly from onPostxecute in the first run of the app?

.

```
public class EntryActivity extends NfcBaseActivity{

    private LoginWebservice loginWebservice;
    private static final String TAG = EntryActivity.class.getSimpleName(); 
    private Button login;
    private EditText userName;
    private EditText passwordPin;
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
    public static final String CUSTOM_QRCODE_ACTION = "com.carefreegroup.QRCODE_ACTION"; 
    private String carerID;
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    private boolean isValidated = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen); 
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        loginWebservice = new LoginWebservice(this);
        carerID = null;
        firstName = null;
        surName = null;




        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ////////////get user's input///////////


                String compId = "100";
                String theUsername = userName.getText().toString();
                String thePassword = passwordPin.getText().toString();
                String loginType = "1";



                String[] params = new String[]{compId, theUsername, thePassword, loginType};

                //validate user Asynchonously on background thread
                 new AsyncValidateCarer().execute(params);



                Log.e(TAG, "carerid =" + carerID + " firstname = " + firstName + " surnamee = " + surName);
                DateTime now = new DateTime();
                long loginTime = now.getMillis();
                String fullName = firstName +" " + surName;
                Log.e(TAG, "fullname = " + fullName); 

                if(carerID != null){

                ContentValues loginValues = new ContentValues();
                loginValues.putNull(LoginValidate.C_ID_INDEX);
                loginValues.put(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID, carerID);
                loginValues.put(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID, compId);
                loginValues.put(LoginValidate.C_CARER_NAME, fullName);
                loginValues.put(LoginValidate.C_PASSWORD, thePassword);
                loginValues.put(LoginValidate.C_DATE_TIME, loginTime);
                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.insertIntoCarer(loginValues);

                Toast.makeText(
                        EntryActivity.this,
                        "Carer logged in to System",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                isValidated = true;

                Intent intent = new Intent(EntryActivity.this,
                        NfcscannerActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(CUSTOM_QRCODE_ACTION);
                startActivity(intent);


                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(
                            EntryActivity.this,
                            "Please check credentials",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                //////////////validate user/////////////////





            }
        });

        Button changeUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonchangeuser);
        changeUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG, "change user button clicked");
                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.deleteTableCarer();
                Toast.makeText(
                        EntryActivity.this,
                        "Carer logged out",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                EntryActivity.this.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }
        });


    }//end of onCreate

    private void hideSoftKeyboard() {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(passwordPin.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    private class AsyncValidateCarer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContentValues> {

        @Override
        protected ContentValues doInBackground(String... params) {

            ContentValues cv = null;

            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside asynctask");
                cv = loginWebservice.validateCarer(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]);
                 if (cv != null){
                     Log.e(TAG, "cv = not null!");
                 }

            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return cv;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ContentValues result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "inside onpostexecute");

            EntryActivity.this.carerID = (String) result.get("carerID"); 
            EntryActivity.this.firstName = (String) result.get("firstname");
            EntryActivity.this.surName = (String) result.get("surname");
        }
    }

}
```

[update]

```
private class AsyncValidateCarer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            ContentValues cv = null;

            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");
                cv = loginWebservice.validateCarer(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]);
                carerID = (String) cv.get("carerID"); 
                firstName = (String) cv.get("firstname");
                surName = (String) cv.get("surname");
                 if (cv != null){
                     Log.e(TAG, "cv = not null! and exiting doInBackground");
                 }

            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null; 


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AsyncTask will execute asynchronously so you have no guarantee that after the "execute" method call, the task is actually finished. My advice would be to move everything (or at least what is related to those fields) that are after "execute" call in "onPostExecute" method.

The reason why it seems the first click doesn't work and the second works, is that between the first "Login" click and the second one, you wait enough for the AsyncTask to finish. So when you click for the second time you see the results of the first execution. Please add some "Log" messeges in "onPostExecute" to understand what is going on.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I've actually tested this point yesterday by placing Thread.sleep(3000) after the .execute() call. i'll try again with a longer delay

Comment: no just tried it with a delay of 5000, but all three variables are still null

Comment: I've logged out the 3 values in onPostExecute() and they have all been set. Why are they not being set outside the method on the first run?

Comment: I don't think a sleep would solve the problem, because you don't know exactly the sleeping value(it depends of the device, other process that are running) and most important it makes useless the AsyncTask. But what is the order of the Log messages? Does "Log.e(TAG, "fullname = " + fullName);" appear before the Log message(s) in onPostExecute for the first run?

Comment: I've solved it. Thanks anyway. I logged out the start and end of every method call. it was calling doInBackground after excute had finished and the rest of the EntryActivity was executing BEFORE onPostExecute! So i have deleted onPostExecute and updated the UI from doInBackground. I'm not sure if this is the correct way but it works. i'll post the updated AsyncTask. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
carerID = null;
firstName = null;
surName = null;
```

**Remove the above there statements** from the `onCreate()` method, as they have been **initialized to their default values** as they are in the `Class Scope` and are known as `Instance Variables.`

Comment: It didn't make a difference. carerID is still null on first run

Comment: @turtleboy what about the other 2 firstName and surName, and pls do check that are you initializing carerID somewhere as null... cause if other 2 comes, then this one should come too

Comment: All three come back null. All three are set when i press the login button a second time.